# How do I add an image from the web to my html site?

Tags: html

When I add an image to my html website, the image doesn't appear, instead showing the alt text with the icon of a broken image. It's an image I found on the internet and I'm trying to display it on my website without having to download the image and add it through my own directory.

Here's the code that I used:

```
<img scr="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l7-Aq7ODH-bBOoENURKWZ-EEJxjpTQMvluC8-A=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="Shark Dude"/>
```

I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours now and I really don't get what is wrong? If you press on the link, it will show you a picture and nothing else. I basically found this picture on google and then I right-clicked on it and pressed copy image web address.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: img `src`, not `scr`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute your want on the `img` tag is `src`, not `scr`. This is shorthand for `source`. You can find a reference for `img` (and the other available HTML tags) at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/

Comment: Ahh, a typo... Thank you!